# Notifications: quizzes, messages, etc

Tags: desire2learn

The Valence API docs here:

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#id1

... mention several methods with the /notifications/instant/ route. However, none of these as described actually provide the notifications sent to the user and displayed in the Updates box.

Are there methods that provide the notifications themselves? If so, where can I find documentation on them?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notifications routes that you refer to let a calling client configure the destinations for sending notifications to a user's mobile device, they do not allow access to the notification data itself. Currently, the Valence Learning Framework API only provides read access to the contents of a [user's feed](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/news.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-feed-), but no other APIs around user notifications.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Assuming you can do such a thing, please add a thumb/+1/whatever for that live message info to be included in the API.

Comment: The Desire2Learn Member Community has a tool to track incoming ideas and enhancement requests  (https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394). If you are not yet a member of this community, you can enroll for a membership (https://community.desire2learn.com/login/enroll.asp).